# click() по type=file в Опере 10.00

Tags: jquery, opera

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" style="position: fixed; top: 9999px;" id="file">
<a href="javascript://" onclick="add_image()">Прикрепить изображение</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add_image() {
  $('#file').click();
}
</script>
```

В опере 10 не вызывается окно с выбором файла. Как быть иначе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно все.

```
<input type="file" style="opacity: 0" />
```

А под ним - уже ссылки ваши всякие.

Извращенцы, вперееед!

BTW: opacity в разных браузерах реализуется по-разному. Особенно, в старых. Но это, думаю, проблемой уже не будет.

UPD: IE просто позволяет передавать события клика по этому инпуту, зато некоторые версии по-дефолту запрещают стилизацию. Понимаете намек?
НАМЕК: для ИЕ, как всегда, приготовьте отдельное решение, которое будет реализовывать именно триггер клика, пряча инпут далеко внизу, как у вас.

Comment: @knes, так проблема в том, когда нет всяких прозрачностей у инпута, всё равно click() по ссылке не срабатывает.

Comment: и не надо. Пусть будет клик по ИНПУТУ. Но юзерь об этом знать не будет, так как глазами он увидит только ссылку. То что сверху над ней прозрачный инпут ловит клики - только программист и знает.

Comment: @knes, во! Точно!

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это возможно. Это вроде как небезопасно. Поэтому браузеры к подобному роду коду относятся плохо и выбрасывают или исключение или просто игнорируют.

Честно сказать я не уверен в том, что говорю. Но давно еще тоже сталкивался с такой проблемой. Гугл мне ясно дал понять, что это небезопасно и браузеры против подобного рода действий.

Comment: @KryDos, интересно, как подобная вещь реализована в ВК..

Answer (score 0):

Гораздо правильнее вместо эмуляции клика использовать `label`:

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" style="position: fixed; top: 9999px;" id="file">
<label for="file">Прикрепить изображение</label>
```